# How to create multiple folders using Azure DevOps Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using Azure DevOps rest api , to create folder in Releases.
Not sure, how can I create multiple folders, subfolders  in same path?

code :

'

```
Param( 
[string]$organisation = "org", 
[string]$project = "testdatafactory", 
[string]$keepForever = "true", 
[string]$user = "id", 
[string]$token = "token",
[string]$path= "\\") 

$headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)")) }

$uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$organisation/$project/_apis/release/folders/$path ?api-version=6.0-preview"


Write-Host "Uri :" $uri

$params = 
@"
{
    "createdBy": "id",
    "createdOn": "",
   "description": "test",
   "lastChangedBy": "",
   "lastChangedDate": "",
   "path": "test1"
    }
"@


$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $params -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Verbose -Debug
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I create multiple folders, subfolders in same path?

I am afraid there is no such out of box way to create multiple folders, subfolders in same path.

That because there is no such Batch REST API for the [Folders - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/folders/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

As workaround, we could run the REST API multiple times to create the multiple folders, subfolders.

We could use the REST API:

```
POST https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/folders?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

Then specify the full path in the request body:

```
{
    "path": "\\Master\\test5",
    "createdBy": "id"
}
```

The test result:

[image]

[image]

And if we want to create the subfolders in the same path, we could just specify the path like: `"path": "\\Master\\test5\\subfolder1"`:

[image]